# Running json files on the apache http server (localhost)

Tags: json, apache, localhost

I am trying to put a json file on a localhost to call later on my app.
How do I put the Json file on to the Apache http server to call later?

---

I am new to Apache http server and back end in general, I am sorry if this question is ambiguous. 
I tried to look up similar questions on stackoverflow..but I just could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the File into your htdocs directory. You can access it by entering in your local Browser:

```
http://localhost/myfilename.json
```